# reflexive-transitive closure of --->, how to understand that?

Tags: type-theory

given term t and t', decide whether t --->* t' -/->, where --->* is the reflexive-transitive closure of --->.

Above two lines are from a paper about programming language meta-theory. I did not understand it. [look at last second page of original paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/dimitris/poplmark.pdf)

(cannot print exact arrow symbols, so printed as above.)
( there are three arrow symbols: (1) --->*  (2) -/-> (3) ---> )
as I know (1) means term t reduced to t' in multiple steps
(2) means not reduced to ..
(3) reduced in a single step

could anyone explain me or point me out some reference which helps me?

Comment: It sounds like: write a code to test if, given two terms $t,t'$ of language $F_<$, we can "produce" $t'$ starting from $t$ - according to the rules - in one step ($\to$), in more than one step ($\to^*$) or not at all ($\nrightarrow$).

Comment: Then all 3 tasks in the original paper sounds almost same thing to me. why put them as 3 tasks? I think I am missing something or thinking too much.